# How do I invoke a click inside of a webbrowser using the div id

Tags: vb.net-2010

Div ID: ct100_cphRoblox_CommentsPane_BlueCommentBtn
Class: BlueCommentBtn

Please help, I just need to invoke a press on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to run something attached to its onclick handler you can;

```
Dim id As String = "ct100_cphRoblox_CommentsPane_BlueCommentBtn"     
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(id).InvokeMember("click")
```

(Similarly `.InvokeMember("onmousedown")` et. al)

Comment: Gets a error, object refernce not set to a instance of a object.
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} I think it may be a link. It may not be a REAL button.

Comment: It does not need to be a real button, DIVs have click events too. Are you waiting for the page to fully load? I.e only trying to access the dom after webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted ?

Comment: I don't know :L. I'm not very good with this kind of stuff. Let me get a  picture of the code, and i'll send you it.

Comment: Here's the picture of the html code: http://s1147.beta.photobucket.com/user/bdfrady/media/picofcode2_zps00d7cefb.png.html

Comment: If you *are* waiting for the document complete event (on the correct document if there are frames) you would need to provide the url to the real page